# Show table data on different page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website where users can write posts, however im haveing trouble echoing the post along with its title.

Heres My Code:

### Post.inc.php:

```
echo '<input type="button" value="Read More" 
onclick="window.location=\'read_more.php?start=' . 
urlencode($row['post']) . ' \';" />';
echo "</p>";
```

### Read_more.php:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
include 'post.inc.php';
?>

<?php
$start = (!empty($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : false);
echo '<p>. $title .<br> ' . $start . '<p>';
?>
```

Only the post is being echoed and not the title. How would I go about fixing this problem?

-Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use variables in single quotes... or you missed placed your two of your quotes. Also this is open to XSS injections.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris said, this is very vulnerable to XSS attacks, you need to sanitize the $_GET['start'] value before echoing it. Also, passing the entire post in the url is not a great idea. If you are storing the post in a database you are better off sending an ID value of some sort through the URL, validating/sanitizing it and retrieving the post directly from the database to be displayed.

I cannot see where you have given $title a value. It is not defined in any of the code you have provided. This means it cannot display anything when echoed.

Also, the structure of your echo is incorrect.

```
echo '<p>'. $title .'<br>'. $start .'</p>';
```

is what you are looking for here. notice the single quotes are closed before $title and re-opened before the break tag.

Answer (score 0):

1. variable will not be expanded when it occur in single quoted strings.You can find this notice in [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

   so,

   `echo '<p>. $title .<br> ' . $start . '<p>'`

   should be modified to

   `echo '<p>'. $title .'<br>'. $start .'</p>';`

   or use double quoted instead,

   `"<p>{$title}<br>{$start}</p>"`
2. As Matt said, echoing the $_GET['start'] directly will make your site be vulnerable,which can result in attacks like phishing.

   In a general way, there are some  operations like filter,type check to sanitize the value gained from frontend. The PHP Manual provides a lot of function to do this,`intval()`,`PCRE`,`mysqli_escape_string()`,`array_filter()`,`htmlspecialchars()`...
3. IMHO,you should use a SQL server like MySQL,SQLite,or others to storage the data from frontend which can help your site work better.